# Unit testing a hybrid angular/react app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, reactjs, karma-runner

I have an large angular application and I'm trying to incrementally convert it over to React. So one of my angular directives renders a div with an id, and the controller will use `ReactDOM.render` to render the React component to that div.

Everything is working great except unit testing. There is already a whole slew of unit tests using karma and angular's testing suite, and they throw an error when I call `ReactDOM.render` because there is no document to getElementById. Angular's testing framework lets you `$compile` your angular code so you can run unit tests without using the DOM.

I hope someone has run into this issue before -- any ideas how to get React unit tests working alongside Angular unit tests using Karma?

Answer (score 0):

Are these unit tests or integration tests? If you can treat them as true unit tests, one approach might be to test pieces in isolation. Write tests for your React components separately, and stub out calls to `ReactDOM.render` In your angular tests. Instead, your angular tests should only test the functionality specific to your angular code, and treat your React code as a separate system.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Karma, the document will be defined. If you set a breakpoint on the line that throws an error, what does `window` look like?